# Mapping being cleared by seemingly unrelated code?

Tags: c#, automapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>();
var test1 = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Foo,Bar>(); //this succeeds
var foos = db.Foos.ToList();
var test2 = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Foo,Bar>(); //this returns null
```

Why would the call to ToList(if I remove ToList it works fine) cause the mapping to no longer exist?

Comment: Are you using L2S, EF or something else there? Framework version, automapper version etc maybe useful.

Comment: db.Foos is entity framework code first.  Automapper v2.0.0.232 installed via NuGet.

Comment: Your simple example works on my machine, therefore you are leaving out relevant detail. Try creating a standalone reproducible example and re-posting.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot to go on here; I set up a simple implementation on my machine and it worked just fine. My best guess is that your model is a little more complex and the EF query has a side-effect of dynamically producing one or more types derived from Foo that AutoMapper doesn't know how to map to Bar. The `ToList()` significance is just that this runs the query which is deferred up to this point. Try setting

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

before running the query and see if it still happens.

Comment: Even if ToList produced derived types, in this code I am not even attempting to convert the Foos.  I am not passing `foos` to AutoMapper at all, so it really shouldn't be involved.  I am calling FindTypeMapFor to demonstrate that the mapping is being removed somehow.  I have had to save the mapping from CreateMap to an instance property of my class to ensure it doesn't disappear.  I don't know if maybe it is getting garbage collected somehow if I don't have a reference to it.  I suppose I could look up the source code for FindTypeMapFor and see what collection it's referencing.

Comment: I will try your suggestion though and see how that pans out.